# What is prototype? Constructor function or a different object?

Tags: javascript

According to this page of [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp), an object prototype is the constructor function that creates an object(Please mention if I have incorrectly interpreted this). And, according to one of my Javascript books, prototype is an object itself. But, when I do this:

JS:

```
function helloObject(name , id , age){
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.age = age;
}

document.getElementById("testElement").textContent = typeof helloObject;//returns function
```

I get that prototype is nothing but the constructor function. So, which one of the two arguments is correct?

Comment: W3Schools is entirely wrong to lump the prototype and the constructor together. **W3S is often wrong,** you shouldn't rely in them too much at all.

Answer (score 3):

Constructor is a function. That's why `typeof helloObject` return `function`.
Every function has a property called "prototype". This `prototype` property is an object. You can check it out writing helloObject.prototype. 
But, prototype object is used only when you are using your function(in your case helloObject) as a constructor, i.e. with keyword `new`. So when you run `var obj = new helloObject()`, you have a new object in `obj` variable and this object has your `name, id, age` properties. But implicitly, javascript writes `__proto__` property in you new object and assigns `prototype` property of the constructor to `__proto__`. Check this out in your console:

```
function helloObject(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
var obj = new helloObject('Your name');

console.log(helloObject.prototype)
console.log(obj.__proto__)
console.log(helloObject.prototype === obj.__proto__) // = true
```

`Prototype` property of the function usually used for inheritance in javascript. Here is couple of posts that can help understand `prototype` better:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/prototypes-in-javascript--net-24949

https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/